# Tag Badge rewording

Tags: feature-request, tags, wording

I was looking into the Tag Badge page, the text for the Silver says, "You'll have to earn 400 upvotes in non-community wiki questions to achieve this badge."  I was wondering whether that meant questions or answers or both (knowing it at least meant answers), since they have columns for askers as well as answers.  A little research showed that it meant answers only.  How about we reword it to,

"You'll have to earn 400 upvotes in *answers to* non-community wiki questions to achieve this badge."

The same for gold also.

Comment: At first I was a bit confused because the text for the badge says answers, but you're referring to the text in the right margin. Which I agree should be reworded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya. This is confusing... probably it should be fixed. (Though it should be kind of obvious - why would you get a badge for asking questions?)

Comment: It confusing because they give Stats for Tag askers also, but I guess to no purpose.

Comment: There are a few things 'to no purpose'...